# How to get db "state version seq" in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, metadata

I need to run a script on every database change. The script works on diffs, so I need to know if I handled the previous state (the handler script could be down for some time for example).

One way I could implement it is to create a trigger on every change which would increment a sequence. Then I just check if `current_sequence_value == previous_sequence_value + 1`.

I'm not that happy with making every single write require the sequence update, so the question is: **can I get such "state version seq" using some kind of built-in metadata?**

Comment: You want to run a script for every DML statement? I hope you have only few data modifications. Maintaining a sequence for that will be your least performance problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Compared to the number of reads, I have very little writes. Also, the script first checks if a certain condition is met (based on the change in the db), which will be met for a tiny fraction of changes. Also the script execution is asynchronous. So I think I should be fine.

Comment: Then use a sequence. They have little overhead.

Comment: be aware that you can't `rollback` updates to sequences.